# Run powershell with parameters and hide flag

Tags: powershell, windows-10, autohotkey

According to the [AHK Docs on `Run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm), it accepts the following syntax:

```
Run, Target , WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID
```

Where `Options` can include:

> - **`Max`**: launch maximized
> - **`Min`**: launch minimized
> - **`Hide`**: launch hidden (cannot be used in combination with either of the above)

I have shortcut bound to a powershell script like this:

```
^4::
Run, pwsh -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1"
Return
```

However, as noted in [Powershell -WindowStyle Hidden still shows a window briefly](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028), this doesn't prevent a brief flash of the console starting up

I can't quite seem to get the syntax right when adding `hide`. When I try this:

```
Run, pwsh, -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1", Hide
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

**Q**: How can I use the `hide` flag on the run command while still passing params into powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to run:

```
Run, pwsh -Command "Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1", , Hide
```

Or using the *modern expression syntax*:

```
Run, % "pwsh -Command ""Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1""", , Hide
```

---

The way your code is currently written:

```
Run, pwsh, -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1", Hide
```

As you pointed out, the parameters are `Target, WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID`, so you're trying to launch `pwsh` in the directory `-WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Stop-ElgatoKeyLight -Host 192.168.1"`.